# Xubuntu - Reverse scrolling in Chrome and Natural scrolling in Firefox with the same setting

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, touchpad, lts, scrolling

I'm on Xubuntu 20.04.2, and in the 'Mouse and Touchpad' setting, I have 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad' enabled and 'Reverse scroll direction' is checked.

With this, I see that I'm able to perform Reverse Scrolling with Chrome and Natural Scrolling with Firefox.

Personally, I prefer Natural Scrolling, but that's something which I've not been able to accomplish by tweaking the settings.

Now, if I un-check the 'Reverse scroll direction', Chrome still stays with Reverse Scrolling but Firefox reverts to Reverse Scrolling.

I suspect this is a bug specific to Chrome in Xubuntu LTS, and I'd appreciate if there are any workarounds to mitigate this.

Thank you.